# Hide cloud music in iOS 8.4

Tags: music.app

When syncing playlists over from iTunes on my Windows Media Center, I have checked the "Only Sync Checked Songs" and it all worked perfectly prior to iOS 8.4.  Also, prior to iOS 8.4, I was able to hide songs that were available in the cloud but not yet downloaded on the device.

After upgrading, however, I'm getting some random songs that I don't even have in my playlist showing up on the phone.  I suspect it has to do with these songs being available in the cloud, but for the life of me I cannot find the option to hide these songs.

I thought maybe I needed to reset the phone and restore everything.  That worked great for a few days, but now I'm seeing these songs show up again.

What is the new way to hide cloud songs with the new Music App?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I toggled the setting as per Alain King's answer, but it did not immediately fix the problem.  However, I did reboot the phone and my playlist is cleaned up.  So I'm going to claim that toggling that setting then rebooting the phone fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

On the my music tab, click the drop down in the centre (mine says artists).  At the bottom of the list is the Show iTunes Purchases toggle.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that option moved, but unfortunately that toggle is not on.